# How to compare two range and set values in a third table with google sheet script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am trying to compare some values in a table (AreaF1) with values in another table (AreaSW). Then, if they match, I set corresponding value of the column in the same column and row of a third sheet (AreaF2) [that is a copy of the first one (AreaF1)]

I tried this code, written using existing examples, but it does not work at all. No errors given. Any idea about how to make it work?

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Menu')
      .addItem('Calc', 'SWFC')
      .addToUi();
}

function SWFC() {
  var Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var AreaF1 = Sheet.getSheetByName('Foglio1').getRange(2, 3, 272, 22).getValues();
  var AreaF2 = Sheet.getSheetByName('Foglio2').getRange(2, 3, 372, 22);
  var Dim2 = AreaF2.getValues();
  var AreaSW = Sheet.getSheetByName('Foglio3').getRange(1, 1, 3, 2).getValues();
  
  for (var i = 0; i<AreaF1.length; i++){
    for (var f = 0; f<Dim2.length; f++){
      for (var k = 0; k<AreaSW.length; k++){
        if(AreaF1[i][f] == AreaSW[k][1]){
            Dim2[i][f] = AreaSW[k][2];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  AreaF2.setValues(Dim2);
}
```

Comment: `AreaF1` and `Dim2` are 2D arrays of m rows by n columns.  If you want to compare each cell of `AreaF1` with `AreaSW` i believe `f` should be `for (var f = 0; f<AreaF1[0].length; f++)` or the the number of columns of `AreaF1`.  If m = 10 and n = 20 you will never compare columns beyond 10.  And if m = 100 and n =10 you will be comparing with undefined values.

Comment: It is a rectangle (something like 22*372), so do you suggest to do a for foreach dimension?
In any case you are right, that is not a good code there, I update it and try again. Luckily "horizontal length" is fixed

Answer (score 0):

Changing the "for" code section solved the problems. I decided to put fixed length for second and third for due to my personal needs.

```
  for (var i = 0; i<AreaF1.length; i++)
  {
    for (var j = 0; j<22; j++)
    {
      for (var k = 0; k<AreaSW.length; k++)
      {
        if(AreaF1[i][j] == AreaSW[k][0])
        {
           Dim2[i][j] = AreaSW[k][1];
        }
      }
    }
  }
```